# How to set each column in a CSV file as a sample instead of each row in neural network?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to do my first machine learning with unstructured data.
The training data after preprocessed is stored in a CSV file, and each column as a sample. After running

```
numpy_array.shape
```

The result is `(240000, 400)`which means there are totally 400 samples, each sample has 240000 features. There are no headers(string) in the training dataset.
My question is how to let the model know, each column is a sample. Should I do a transpose to the training dataset first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transpose the dataset via `np.transpose(your_array)` or `your_array.T`
the shape will be `(400, 240000)` with each sample as a row